# The target origin provided ('<URL>') does not match the recipient window's origin ('<URL>')

Tags: javascript

Please check this. I am getting this error in my console.

Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('') does not match the recipient window's origin ('').

this is the page i need help with
https://horrorstoryhouse.com/horror-stories-in-urdu/

Comment: i am not a programmer

Comment: So what you do is to [paste the error into google](https://www.google.com/search?q=youtube+Failed+to+execute+%27postMessage%27+on+%27DOMWindow%27:+The+target+origin+provided+(%27%3CURL%3E%27)+does+not+match+the+recipient+window%27s+origin+(%27%3CURL%3E%27).+site:stackoverflow.com) and read one of the MANY similar questions

Comment: More here https://www.google.com/search?q=youtube+widget+Failed+to+execute+%27postMessage%27+on+%27DOMWindow%27